# Changing the icon in actionbar

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar

I would like to place the logo for my application in the actionbar at the top of the screen. Currently displayed is the default green android launcher icon.

[image]

I have tried the following but saw no change:

I went into my manifest file and altered the android:icon code...

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:logo="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

This did not work, So I then created an ActionBar object within my code and used the setIcon method.

```
ab.setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
```

However the above line of code generates the following runtime error:

**java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.waitronproto3/com.example.waitronproto3.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
**

Can anybody see why this is happening, The resource R.drawable.logo exists because I can see it in the folder and no errors are generated within the IDE.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The `nullpointer`, if it on that line is the ActionBar being `null`, not the drawable. Anyways, try cleaning your project, and try using `android:icon` instead of `logo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, there is no `android:logo` property as far as I know. You can't just create an `ActionBar`... have you used this?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(...);
    getActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.logo)`
}
```

Comment: Also post the line that gives you the NPE if you still get it - if you look at the whole stack trace you can see a "caused by" line which tells you more about the exception.

Comment: Your answer helped me solve the problem. All I was required to do was get a reference to my actionbar which I had not done before I tried to set the icon.

Answer (score 0):

Everything was right except I forgot to get a reference to the ActionBar. The code below solved the problem.

```
ab = this.getActionBar();
    ab.setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
```